# Embed custom google map in webpage

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-maps

I have created a custom Map on Google.

This is the link for this

> https://mapsengine.google.com/map/edit?mid=zBAGtTBRumkA.k4-cAR2S6t34

my problem is that when I am embed this map to my website, it is showing side bar (positions).

I want to remove the side bar, how can i do it.

Comment: How do you embed it? What are you trying to do? Have you used the [maps api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial)?

Comment: I have embed this by using <iframe src="http://mapsengine.google.com/map/embed?mid=zBAGtTBRumkA.k4-cAR2S6t34" width="640" height="480"></iframe>

Comment: Do you mean you don't want it to show the box with the locations in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this solution will work. Add css to your page

```
#featurelist-pane{display:none;}
```

Comment: can you create a fiddle? or atleast update your question post code here.

Comment: Ok, I am creating a fiddle

Comment: this is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jcC2w/ but it is not showing sidebar without any effort, but in my page it is displaying

Comment: have you implemented my solution?? are you using external css to achieve this?? if yes please clear you browser cache

Comment: I have implemented your solution, and I have cleared the cache, but problem is same

Comment: are you using chrome?? if yes then inspect element and see if you see those css changes

Comment: your fiddle iframe src is different that what you have posted in question.

Comment: You cannot edit it. You are trying to edit an external website, you can't use a iframe if you want to edit it in anyway. You will need to use the Google Maps API

Answer (score 0):

In your Css:

```
 .b0t70b-haAclf {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your css:

```
<div id="featureListPanel" class="b0t70b-haAclf" style="display: block; width: 280px; z-index: 0; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 18px;">
```

Change:

```
display: block;
```

To:

```
display: none;
```